# Scala - pattern matching and doing something BEFORE the match.

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I want to execute a statement before I match.

```
def test(x : Int) = x match {
      doSomethingHere always
      case 1 => println("1")
      case 2 => println("2")
    }
```

It has to be before, so I can't just match on _ and execute at the end. It could go before I run test(), but I'd rather keep it inside the function.

Comment: Why not just make this function call another function that does the matching?

Comment: No reason. But if could be done without, why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then say

```
def test(x : Int) = {
    doSomethingHere always
    x match {
      case 1 => println("1")
      case 2 => println("2")
    }
}
```

which precisely and without boilerplate expresses what you're trying to accomplish.  Is there any issue here, beyond a stray {} pair?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise you could do the match anywhere you wanted. For some reason I'd associated it entirely with coming directly after a function definition

Comment: Yup, match is just another statement type, like for, while and if.  Any number of the can be chained into a method body, just by wrapping them in {}.  Your questions weirdly enough makes moe sense in Haskell, where pattern matching is integrated into the function (method) declaration syntax.